# Referenced files not found in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I followed this [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html) to set up Angular2 in Visual Studio 2015.

The project starts, and all seems fine. However I noticed these errors in the VS output window:

> 10:59:59.8753: Referenced file
>   'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js' not found.
>
> 10:59:59.8763: Referenced file 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js' not
>   found.
>
> 10:59:59.8763: Referenced file
>   'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js' not found.
>
> 10:59:59.8763: Referenced file
>   'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js' not found.

The 4 files actually exist in the destination folders, so I'm unsure what the problem is. Any advice?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: @FelipeAlarcon: v. 6.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this however there seems to be a problem with the way the quick start project is setup. I saw a similar issue and found that node_modules exist under

```
VisualStudioProject\node_modules\
```

but the error is for

```
VisualStudioProject\src\node_modules\
```

I found the following article very helpful in creating my own quick start project.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1164014/Kick-Start-with-AngularJS-and-Visual-Studio